# Waterproof connector to hack electric toothbrush

Tags: connector, waterproof

I have an Oral-B Triumph 5000 whose battery needs replacement.

I would like to bring out the positive and negative connectors to both allow external charging/discharging/refresh (external smart chargers like BC-700 do a better task) and to allow plug-in operation with an external 1.5V power supply.

The space inside the device is very limited, so I don't know which connector I would be able to add inside the casing (see this [Youtube video](https://youtu.be/PBYXM11dZMk?t=1m57s)) so I may need to bring out a cable with a power connector.

Even keeping in mind that I can build small objects with a 3D printer, I don't know which power connector (hopefully small, not a big, screw-in, industrial connector) are available for use/modification: during cleaning and during operation plenty of liquids flow around. During operation in battery-only mode, the connector should not expose the contacts (directly connected to the internal battery), to avoid shorting them out.

Which small connector (like audio jack, but waterproof) or which external, cabled and compact waterproof connector are available for the purpose, rated for 2A operation?

I was able to find this one: https://www.adafruit.com/product/743 but I cannot find the exact model number to know more about it, and also when disconnected (battery operation in my case) the contacts are exposed. I would need to build a plug (silicone?) myself to close them.

**Edit**: the question was asked here because it seems that waterproof electrical connectors are part of this website, see tags "waterproof, connectors".

Comment: You've got votes to close.  This is a pretty striaght forward "asking for a recommendation" question, and they are off topic.  You'd do better to ask how to find the correct type of connector, or to find something that seems to fit your needs and ask if it really does what you are looking for.

Comment: Waterproof connectors are a huge pain - I think most manufacturers have moved to wireless charging for this purpose.

Comment: Rechargeable toothbrushes have used wireless charging since (at least) the late 1990's when I bought my first one.  The one being dealt with here originally used wireless charging, but has already been cracked open and modified once to use a non-standard battery.

Comment: @JRE done, also improved the question to make it clearer and with more useful info

Comment: @pjc50 sure but the wireless charge system is slow, while batteries in the 2000 mAh range (2200 the original one, 2000 the one I have now) prefer 0.5-1C charge rates for proper -dV termination, otherwise only overvoltage detection is possible, but it's less accurate. Moreover, a complete refresh by using the toothbrush until depletion is not optimal, since the discharge current is too high for the purpose (1C or more during operation).

Comment: Consider http://www.digikey.com/en/product-highlight/s/switchcraft/sealed-power-plugs-jacks - IP68 is suitable for continuous immersion. Obviously you should make sure the seal *round* the connector is good too!